# DAE file parsing error

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit, blender

I have exported a **sphere.dae** file from **Blender** and imported in Xcode. This mesh file has texture and normal maps. I have applied the textures and normal maps to the sphere file in the Scenekit editor and the mesh file is properly visible in the editor.

However, when I deploy the build on real iOS device, I get the following error:

```
[SceneKit] Error: failed to parse key path /Roundcube_003.geometry.materials - missing '['
```

On the device, the sphere mesh file is visible but the **textures are not visible**. I have following questions:

1. Is this the problem from Blender or Xcode? Other mesh files exported from the Blender are properly visible.
2. The error suggests that the Scenekit is not able to parse the materials data from the mesh file. Is this understanding correct? If yes, how can I fix this issue?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: I had similar issue in Zbrush, the culprit was polypaint, and I think blender does support vertex color aswell. Just open the obj or dae file in a text editor and you'll see the part that scenekit doesn't like. Can you post a sample DAE file ?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  would love to know how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to your reference overrides of the objects. I had the same problem. All you have to do is to remove the reference overrides, you can find the overrides at the third bar of the right side panel (not sure of the name)